# Locomotive Scroll and pageYOffset

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, locomotive-scroll

How can scrollTo-back button be seen after scrolling a certain scrolling-height when using Locomotive scroll and pageYOffset?

I was trying to use pageYOffset but is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.